# Magento | Logged in customers can't send orders to a new address only the default address work!

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, customer-account

Our Website is Magento based and I have a problem:

When a customer logged in and go to My Address in Account page then Add Address this address will be the default for both billing and shipping.If you need to send the order to another address and select new address it always use the default which is a big problem for our store!!

How can we solve this problem? Thanks:)